# Looping the multiple files in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I need to loop through the files given as input.

```
FILE_NAME = {1}#is a .txt file
for f in `ls -C1 ${FILE_NAME}.txt`
```

I am getting error “ ‘FOR’ is not matched”. Please help me on this!

Comment: What you try to do? Save the command in a variable or what? pls edit the question.

Comment: If `FILE_NAME` is `some_file.txt`, then `${FILE_NAME}.txt` equals `some_file.txt.txt`, isn't it? :-)

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

If your input name is a STDIN then:

```
#!/bin/ksh

FILE_NAME=$l

for f in $(ls -C1 $FILE_NAME.txt)
do
     echo $f
done
```

Else if your input is an accept user input then:

```
#!/bin/ksh

read FILE_NAME

for f in $(ls -C1 $FILE_NAME.txt)
do
     echo $f
done
```

Instead if you should to iter a file list from a prefix:

```
#!/bin/ksh

read PREFIX_NAME

for f in $(ls -C1 $PREFIX_NAME*.txt)
do
     FILE_NAME = $f
done
```

Thank you

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Without parsing ls output can you try so: 

#!/bin/ksh

FILE_NAME=$0

MY_DIR="./"
cd $MY_DIR

for f in *
do
   if [ $f == $FILE_NAME ]
   then
     echo $f
   fi

done